# ESP8266 reseted due to relay / AC plugged

Tags: esp8266, relay, reset

My Wemos card is reseting for unknown reason. For example, the pump plugged on the relay works fine till 1am and then the pump stop. After a few research I figured out the ESP should reset because all internal parameters are reseted.
[image]

My hardware is simple Wemos card + relay + sensors (not here because not connected yet).
[image]

My program is quite complex. I can command/configure the wemos via webservice (ex relay on pin 5 with on 5min/off 10min).
https://github.com/TittyPanda/ESP-commander/blob/master/ESP-COMMANDER

- OK if no AC device is connected on relay (no reset)
- OK if a light is connected on relay
- The issue occurs only when the water pump is connected

Maybe it's an electrical/electromagnetical thing because the pump has motor. What do you think ?

Thanks,

**EDIT**
Power part are done with common wires from power extension cord

[AC-DC converter 5 V 1A 1.5A 500mA](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32800561583.html)
[image: C-DC converter]

[Pump 40W 3000L/H 220V 50Hz](https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B07B8MHYCP)
[image: Pump]

Comment: What is your pump current consumption? this sound like that you have a power supply that can't deliver sufficient power to the overall circuitry.

Comment: It could well be EMI induced by the pump. You need to specify more details about exactly what hardware you're using - what pump, what power supplies, what wiring, etc.

Comment: Thanks I added pump & converter info in the post

Comment: @hcheung I'm not sure because the whole system works fine when nothing is plugged on relays (I'm testing a light again but during 24h)

Comment: try a shorter and thicker extension cord, and a large capacitor (1000uf+) on the 5v rail.

Comment: I installed the L-C Power Filter between the breadboard and ESP as advised by @gdb.
24 h - no reset -> it was the solution.
Thanks all of you for your help and your time.
The topic is closed for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add some power filter like this:
[image: An LC filter]

[image: Filter image]

Between the breadboard and ESP board.

Comment: Thanks @gbg It remains me my electronic/physic courses :) - found with  L-C Power Filter and google image ! https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32842662140.html

Comment: it was the solution